# Proof by induction with factorials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I need help with proving this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{i!}=\frac{n!-1}{n!}$$

My induction hypothesis is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{i!}+\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)}$$

I tried a few things and landed here:

$$\frac{(n+1)n!-1+n}{(n+1)n!}=\frac{(n+1)n!-1}{(n+1)n!}$$

there is one $n$ too much in my last equation and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Well, since that equation *isn't* true how'd you end up there.  We can't tell you how to fix it if we don't know why you got there is in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you must prove that $$\frac{n!-1}{n!}+\frac{n+1-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: I tried this already and ended up with the third equatio I posted.

Comment: @Peet Note that $\frac{n!-1}{n!}=1-\frac1{n!}$ and $\frac{n+1-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}-\frac1{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n!}-\frac1{(n+1)!}$ and $\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=1-\frac1{(n+1)!}$. There is no magic involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your induction hypothesis should be the formula you're trying to prove. As in:

> Assume $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{i!}=\frac{n!-1}{n!}$

You're trying to prove the formula obtained by replacing every copy of $n$ with $n+1$ in the above formula. As in:

> We wish to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{i-1}{i!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{i!}=\frac{n!-1}{n!}\ \ \ \ \  (1)$$
You want to prove if $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{i-1}{i!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$$
Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i-1}{i!}+\frac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}\underbrace{\implies}_{(1)}\frac{n!-1}{n!}+\frac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the indices on the first sum of $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}  \frac{n!-1}{n!}+\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)}$$ to $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}  \frac{i!-1}{i!}+\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)}$$

Answer (score -1):

"My induction hypothethesis is

$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{i!}+\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)}$"

WHY?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?

$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac {i -1}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {i-1}{i} + \frac {n+ 1 - 1}{(n+1)!}$ and $\frac {n+1 - 1}{(n+1)!} \ne \frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$  And setting $n\to n+1$ will give you  $\frac {n!-1}{n!} \to \frac {(n+1)! - 1}{(n+1)!}$ and not $\frac{(n+1)! - 1}{n+1}$.

Surely you induction hypothethesis should have been

$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac {i -1}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {i-1}{i} + \frac {n+ 1 - 1}{(n+1)!}= \frac {(n+1)! -1}{(n+1)!}$

Which is a matter of proving

$\frac {n! - 1}{n!} + \frac {n}{(n+1)!} = \frac {(n+1)! -1}{(n+1)!}$

which should be very easy to prove:

$\frac {n! - 1}{n!} + \frac {n}{(n+1)!} =

$\frac {(n! - 1)(n+1)}{n!(n+1} + \frac {n}{(n+1)!} =$

$\frac {(n+1)! - (n+1)}{(n+1)!} + \frac n{(n+1)!} =$

$\frac {(n+1)! - n - 1 +n}{(n+1)!} = \frac {(n+1)! - 1}{(n+1)!}$.